# Analytical solution from a System of ODE

Tags: differential-equations

Greeting guys. So I'm trying to solve a ODE System but i'm not acquainted with the language that It's used.

> `x'[t] == (F0 - Cv*Sqrt[x[t]])/A1`
> `y'[t] == (Cv*Sqrt[x[t]] - 2*Sqrt[y[t]])/A2`
> `z'[t] == (Cv*Sqrt[y[t]] - Sqrt[z[t]])/A3`
> `w'[t] == (Cv*(Sqrt[y[t]] - Sqrt[z[t]] - Sqrt[w[t]]))/A4`

And now the constants:
`F0 = 2`,
`Cv = 0.8`,
`A1 = 3`,
`A2 = 3.5`,
`A3 = 4`,
`A4 = 3`.

I have tried many functions from the Wolfram Mathematica, but none of them give me a the answer that I'm expecting. I tried *DSolve*, *DSolveValue* and them variations (Numerical and the common one)

The answer that I was looking for is a analytical solution, with step-by-step. With the *WolframAlpha* function i tried to solve this system but i couldn't do it and I don't know why. So If one of you could give me a explanation why, which function can give the solution or give me some links that I can read about e learn it I'll appreciate.

Thank for you attention and have a good day!

Comment: **The answer that I was looking for is a analytical solution** These are coupled non-linear odes. Most nonlinear ode's (even single ones) have no analytical solution. If Mathematica can not solve the ode's analytically, then there is very good chance these have no analytical solution. Try numerical `NDSolve`, that one can solve almost anything since it is numerical.

Comment: If you are looking for step-by-step solution to system of first order ode's, try linear ones. I do not know if Wolfram alpha shows steps or not for these, but that would be first thing to try. W/Alpha normally shows step-by-step for basic problems. Not ones considered much more complicated like this one.

Answer (score 3):

The first equation can be solved for `x`

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

F0 = 2;
Cv = 4/5;
A1 = 3;

eqnx = x'[t] == (F0 - Cv*Sqrt[x[t]])/A1;

solx = DSolve[eqnx, x, t][[1]]

(* Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

{x -> Function[{t}, 
   25/4 (1 + ProductLog[1/5 (E^(-5 - (4 t)/15 + 2 C[1]))^(1/5)])^2]} *)
```

Verifying,

```
Assuming[{t, C[1]} ∈ Reals, eqnx /. solx // Simplify]

(* True *)
```

Graphically,

```
Plot[Evaluate[List @@ eqnx /. solx /. C[1] -> 0], {t, -10, 10},
 AxesLabel -> {Style[HoldForm@t, 14], None},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[List @@ eqnx, {.2, .7}]]
```

[image]